# Play mediaplayer for certain duration

Tags: android, video, audio, media-player

I want to play the mediaplayer for just 10 sec. How to control it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html can give a list of properties that you can use to control your media player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TimerTask` to schedule a `MediaPlayer.stop()` to run after 10 secs.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) that will stop your [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). so you will not have to implement a thread or something.