# Pause/Stop MediaPlayer Android at given time programmatically

Tags: android, media-player

I researched a little bit, but couldn't find any solutions to this problem:
I would like to play a `MediaPlayer` and pause/stop it at a given time.. (ie: play from second 6 to second 17).

I know that I can set its starting point with `seekTo()` method, but can I pause/stop it from playing by setting an end point (of course, before reaching the file end limit)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are different ways you could do this, here's one:

```
int startFrom = 6000;
int endAt = 11000;

MediaPlayer mp;

Runnable stopPlayerTask = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mp.pause();
    }};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_sound_file);  
    mp.seekTo(startFrom);
    mp.start();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(stopPlayerTask, endAt);
}
```

The mediaplayer will start playing 6 seconds in and pause it 11 seconds after that (at second 17).

Comment: Why did you use `mp.pause();` instead of `mp.stop();` ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere once stopped it cannot be started again without calling `prepare()`. I prefer pausing if there's a chance I want to play it again. Calling `stop()` is more final.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can create [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and call seekTo() directly from its task. Then call stop()/pause() inside of that Timer Task.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550789/android-simple-how-to-stop-mediaplayer-after-given-time) post will be helpfull for you.

Or you can use handler for this task, like Ken Wolf shows you.

Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice answe too, but I prefer handler, as I would handle easier cases like: user pausing/stopping player by himself.. or having to pause player when Activity stops. (pausing thread after calling sleep() is kinda annoying me :) )

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mp.stop;
         mp.relese();
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: this is not working 100% in some case
if your audio has 33300 then maybe 300milisecond issued.

Answer (score 0):

I know this already has an answer but here is an alternative for anyone wanting to do this efficiently for a video with controls.

I saw a different answer that involved constantly checking the position.

Note that this assumes that you do not need a lot of different portions of one video. Even in that case I suggest to follow the below.

If you only need to play a portion of the video and want it to end somewhere, then why not just use free video editing software and clip the end? You can still start it from anywhere using `seekTo()` but this way you don't have to waste resources checking for a certain position (video with controls).

If you do not have video player controls the accepted answer will work. But if you do have player controls then it would not since a user could pause and play the video.

Answer (score 0):

There's a time difference between videoView.start() and video prepared to play depend on video format, those time difference is probably more than 10 frames.

so the best way to do is to start the timer inside OnPreparedListener to minimise the time difference, or even more to get the current playing duration and set a postDelayed timer at that point.